# Convert AWS EC2 Windows Memory Available (MB) Metric unit to Percent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-auto-scaling

I have a custom metric that gets Available Memory (in MB) from EC2 Windows, while setting up an alarm to kick off scaling, setting the threshold against the available memory does not help and I am looking to get Available memory converted to Percent %,  basically change the metric unit to % which make easy to set the threshold, especially with auto-scaling policy.

I tried converting MemoryMB to Percent while setting up the custom metric configuration like:

`{"name": "Available MBytes", "rename": "MemoryAvailableInMB", "unit": "Percent"}`
but did not help.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.